# URL not found - usando Django y AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-urls

Quiero enviar un dato desde JavaScript hacia una vista en Django, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera (esta función se ejecuta al presionar un botón):

```
function corregir(){
  var data = {'cantidad_correctas': cantidad_correctas};

  var URL = "{% url 'send' %}";
  $.post(URL, data, function(response){
      if(response === 'success'){ alert('Quizz enviado.'); }
      else{ alert('¡Algo salió mal!'); }
  });

  console.log(data);
}
```

Tengo estas dos views en Django,  `quizz` solamente renderiza el html y  `send` es la que debería obtener el valor  `data` de JS:

```
def quizz(request):
    return render(request, "quizz.html")

def send(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'cantidad_correctas' in request.POST:
            cantidad_correctas = request.POST['cantidad_correctas']
            print(cantidad_correctas)
            return HttpResponse('Correcto')
    return HttpResponse('FAIL!!!!!')
```

Y así tengo definidas mis urls:

```
path('quizz/', quizz, name="quizz"),
path('quizz/send', send, name="send"),
```

El console.log(data) sí me muestra el dato que debería enviar a Django, pero obtengo un error 404 en la URL.
[image: Error]

Y del lado de la consola en VSCode, tengo el siguiente error:

[image: Error vscode]

Anteriormente tenía la ruta send solamente como `path('quizz/send', send, name="send")` e incluso tenía configurada la variable de URL así: `var URL = "{% url 'quizz' %}";` y solamente usar los métodos POST dentro de la vista `quizz`, pero nada de ello me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de un rato de buscar información, vi que me hacía falta enviar el `csrf_token` dentro del diccionario.

Para quienes lleguen a toparse con el mismo problema, deben agregar `'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'` dentro de la data que enviarán por POST, tal que así:

```
var data = {'cantidad_correctas': cantidad_correctas,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'};
```